# Почему не отображается инфоблок в редакторе?

Tags: битрикс

Зашёл в админке в "Контент" → "Типы инфоблоков" и создал инфоблок.
Пытаюсь добавить его на страницу через стандартный редактор, но он (редактор) инфоблок не видит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, сохранили ли вы этот инфоблок. И правильно ли выбрали тип инфоблока (это можно определить показываются ли соседские инфоблоки)

Comment: сейчас пришлю скриншот http://pixs.ru/showimage/Bezimyanni_8071316_20592207.png

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: вы не могли бы теперь сфотографировать настройки компонента на странице (редактор), где вы не видите в списке нужный инфоблок?

Comment: Для того, чтобы инфоблок отображался у него на вкладке "Доступ" должно быть выбрано "Чтение". Скорее всего вы не указали настройки доступа, а по-умолчанию они равны "Нет доступа".

Comment: http://pixs.ru/showimage/Bezimyanni_9251935_20593833.png  доступ чтение было

Comment: Пожалуйста, все дополнения к вопросу добавляйте **прямо в вопрос**.

Comment: @НиколайСарры вы совсем заблуждаетесь: создавший инфоблок всегда по умолчанию его видит, если специально не указано обратное. Автор вопроса, конечно, так не мог.

Comment: @higimo: комментарий может быть ошибочным, но он конструктивен. Неконструктивный — это когда совсем не относится к вопросу. Например, неконструктивной здесь была бы критика Битрикса или PHP.

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо за пояснение

Answer (score 1):

Вы ищите иноблок там, где расположены компоненты.

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=35&LESSON_ID=1902&LESSON_PATH=3906.4493.4501.1902 — инструкция по работе с редактором

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZp5l.png — скриншот настроек компонента.

Там, где вы ищите — никогда не появится ни один инфоблок. Тут вы выбираете лишь формат вывода.

Добавьте любой компонент на страницу (если не умеете, ступайте проходить обучение, много вопросов уйдёт). После добавления обязательно увидите похожее на мой скриншот настроек компонента. В нём есть тип инфоблока, и сам инфоблок. Они выбираются через выпадающее меню.